# How to solve 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attname' in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have created a simple model in django models and I have migrated it to my sqllite database. I also created a form that inherits from my model and I have referenced all fields from the form. I am rendering the form to a template but there arises an exception  `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attname'`. My code is as follows:

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    telephone = models.IntegerField()
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __init__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
import re
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from .models import *

class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = "__all__"
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import *
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group


def upload(request):
    form = CustomerForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/templates/upload.html', {'form':form})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns =[
    
    path('upload/', views.upload, name='upload'),
]
```

upload.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}

<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
     {{ form}}
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Traceback

```
Internal Server Error: /upload/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SERU\Desktop\School Projects\Clearance_System\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\SERU\Desktop\School Projects\Clearance_System\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SERU\Desktop\School Projects\Clearance_System\registration\views.py", line 7, in upload
    form = CustomerForm()
  File "C:\Users\SERU\Desktop\School Projects\Clearance_System\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 290, in __init__
    self.instance = opts.model()
  File "C:\Users\SERU\Desktop\School Projects\Clearance_System\registration\models.py", line 25, in __init__
    return self.name
  File "C:\Users\SERU\Desktop\School Projects\Clearance_System\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query_utils.py", line 149, in __get__
    instance.refresh_from_db(fields=[field_name])
  File "C:\Users\SERU\Desktop\School Projects\Clearance_System\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 623, in refresh_from_db
    db_instance_qs = self.__class__._base_manager.db_manager(using, hints=hints).filter(pk=self.pk)
  File "C:\Users\SERU\Desktop\School Projects\Clearance_System\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 573, in _get_pk_val
    return getattr(self, meta.pk.attname)
  File "C:\Users\SERU\Desktop\School Projects\Clearance_System\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query_utils.py", line 147, in __get__
    val = self._check_parent_chain(instance)
  File "C:\Users\SERU\Desktop\School Projects\Clearance_System\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query_utils.py", line 163, in _check_parent_chain
    return getattr(instance, link_field.attname)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attname'
```

Answer (score 1):

To display the object properly in Django admin panel and other places you can return string instead of initializing.

```
class Company(models.Model):
    ----

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception was raised in models.py where  I defined `__init__` method

```
    def __init__(self):
        return self.name
```

to return a string `name` from the company model instead of defing a `__str__` method.
So the solution is to change the method to a string method as shown below.

```
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This works perfectly and it returns the string value as expected.